# Content editor webpart code to add a background image in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: css, content-editor-web-part, picture-library

I have the following code to add a bg image on my Subsite home page. It does'nt seem to work and I have a solid feeling its the way I'm referring the image (stored under a picture library named 'Image Library' on the same subsite). I have it saved in a text file under a document library (also under the same subsite) and then just use that link on the content editor webpart. Test link seems to bring it up just fine, so I am good there. Any ideas on how to get this functional?

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-mainarea{
    background-
    image:url('https://share.ey.net/sites/test/test%20page/Image%20Library/20H00217.jpg'););

}
.s4-ca
{
 background-color:transparent;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Using firebug or IE tool, try adding the background-image property and the source url, see if it changes, also make sure s4-mainarea id exists and try adding div#s4-mainarea {...} or use !important property to see if it overrides the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me. Try to use !important if it doesn't work.

```
#s4-workspace{
background-image: url(../images/image.jpg);
background-size: cover;
overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Comment: Thanks....but for some reason my bg image doesnt really stick. It just seems to flicker for a second and go away. Look like the master page is overriding it

Comment: Try to modify the #s4-workspace from dev tools and see if you could get it to work. Also, try to use !important with the background-image property and see if that works